# VS 2012 VB.NET -- Error when creating a dataset connected to sqlite file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sqlite, dataset

When I use the Database wizard to create a new dataset in Data Sources, I am getting the error:
<"maiin"."MeetingList>
Error in SELECT  clause: expression near','.
Missing FROM clause
Unable to parse query text.

The table definition was created first. The column rowid is there after importing the data from a csv file. The database has just one table and no select statements have been created. The dataset is created but with no fill code.

VS 2012 vb.net

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to parse a CSV file as a SQL statement.  That won't work.

Comment: The csv file has already been imported into the sqlite3 file before the import by using DB Browser for Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Do not use the wizard. Instead right click on the data set window and add the table. That way the queries are created by the designer and the error message from the wizard is avoided.